# Cursor Loader auto-requery on Spinner onSelectedItem call

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-loadermanager, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using a spinner as an actionbar item (also using tab navigation with swipes). 
I have 2 listFragments (accessed via the tabs) that load data using a loader.
I want the loader to requery every time I select a different item in the spinner (which works on the activity level).
That's one of the fragment's loader's call, selectedNumber is a String that should be passed from the spinner onSelectedItem to the fragment (I don't know how yet, but this should be easy).

```
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String selection= MyContentProvider.Data.E_NUMBER +"=";
    String[] selectionArgs= {numberSelected};

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),  MyContentProvider.Data.CONTENT_URI_EVENTS,
            null, selection, selectionArgs,
            Data.E_ID + " DESC");
}
```

Is there a way I can force the loader to requery the content provider or i have to cancel the fragment and build another one with the new query?

(some quick advice on how to pass the String from the activity to both the fragment would be cool)